# sudoers NOPASSWD ineffective in desktop launcher script

Tags: linux, launcher, sudoers

I have a launcher script in Linux Mint 13 so that I can click an icon on the desktop to mount my NAS. In order to use /bin/mount without a password I must add this line to sudoers:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

The script to mount the NAS is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ 0 = `sudo mount |grep -c nasbox` ]
    then
        sudo mount -a
fi
```

If I use a terminal my script works without the need to enter a password but when it is run from a launcher (using "Application in Terminal") it asks for the password. If I give the password it accepts it and runs - so it must know which user is running it and allow the user to use sudo, so it does honour part of sudoers, but it doesn't honour the NOPASSWD keyword for /bin/mount. How do I get the NOPASSWD to work here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete /var/run/sudo, /var/lib/sudo, and /var/db/sudo to flush out anything that sudo may have cached. Then make sure that your system's time and date are set correctly. As a (paranoid) security measure, sudo may prompt for the password if it determines that the system clock is unreliable.

This actually happened to me once on a system without a persistent RTC clock. I think I solved it by removing those directories and setting the system clock to a future value at startup. The sudo utility may have changed by now, so I'm not sure if this still applies, but give it a try!